# How to automate file transformation with simultanous execution?

Tags: bash, automation, transformation, simultaneous

I am working on transforming a lot of image files (png) into text files. I have the basic code to do this one by one, which is really time consuming. My process involves converting the image files into a black and white format and then using tesseract to transform those into a text file. This process works great but it would take days for me to acomplisyh my task if done file by file.
Here is my code:

```
for f in $1
do
 echo "Processing $f file..."
 convert $f -resample 200 -colorspace Gray ${f%.*}BW.png
 echo "OCR'ing $f"
 tesseract ${f.*}BW.png ${f%.*} -l tla -psm 6
 echo "Removing black and white for $f"
 rn ${f%.*}BW.png
done
echo "Done!"
```

Is there a way to perform this process to each file at the same time, that is, how would I be able to run this process simultaneously instead of one by one? My goal is to significantly reduce the amount of time it would take for me to transform these images into text files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how "big" is your computer? Cores/threads? Multiple servers? Can you rent time on the cloud? (Add this info to your question!). Basically, low budget with `bash|ksh` is look at the `--max-procs` option to `xargs`. Next step up would be install `parallel`. After that, you use something like Hadoop or other. Others will offer their favorites. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shellter

Could you provide me with the command to do this? I am very new to the language and using this execution in order to use the data later on for a project. If it helps, I am using a computer with 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo with 8gb DDR3.
Let me add that I have a VERY large amount of pictures that need conversion, and if the process is done one-by-one it would take weeks for it to finish.
Is there a way to do this in terminal? or am I forced to download extensions/other software to accomplish my task?

Thanks again.

Comment: This would take a lot of effort to correctly understand the scope of you project and how available resources could be organized to work most efficiently. If  you can't use a faster/better computer to increase your throughput, then I think your system can support 4 threads processing at the same time. So search here for examples of `find ... | xargs -P (--max-procs` and use the function below. If you're lucky and there aren't any hidden problems in your specification, you might be able to divide your time estimate by 4. As  you're new to this, really try to keep untouched original files safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank contributors @Songy and @shellter.
To answer my question... I ended up using GNU Parallel in order to make these processes run in intervals of 5. Here is the code that I used:

```
parallel -j 5 convert {} "-resample 200 -colorspace Gray" {.}BW.png ::: *.png ; parallel -j 5 tesseract {} {} -l tla -psm 6 ::: *BW.png ; rm *BW.png
```

I am now in the process of splitting my dataset in order to run this command simultaneously with different subgroups of my (very large) pool of images.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could make the content for your for loop a function then call the function multiple times but send each all to the background so you could execute another.

```
function my_process{
    echo "Processing $1 file..."
    convert $1 -resample 200 -colorspace Gray ${1%.*}BW.png
    echo "OCR'ing $1"
    tesseract ${1.*}BW.png ${1%.*} -l tla -psm 6
    echo "Removing black and white for $1"
    rn ${1%.*}BW.png
}

for file in ${files[@]}
do
    # & at the end send it to the background.
    my_process "$file" &
done
```

Comment: `find . -name '*.png'| xargs --max_procs ${maxProcsAvail}` will help O.P. control the number of background processes running. If he has 1000's of files, you won't be able to create bkgrd processes just from one loop, you'll need to wait for processes to become free. `xargs` gives you that for free. Good luck to all.